# Разьясните что это за странная конструкция и что она делает?

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    auto f = [](int a, int b) -> int {
           return a*b;
        };

    return 0;
}
```

компилируется и собирается без проблем.

Comment: лямбда функция возвращающая произведение операндов

Comment: Минутка рекламы. Мои две статьи, которые описывают лямбды в C++: [перва](http://scrutator.me/post/2011/10/14/lamda-auto-decltype.aspx) и [вторая](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/07/08/lambda_auto_decltype_cpp14.aspx)

Comment: Это еще мелочи :) int main(){[](){}();}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Справа от знака `=` — лямбда, анонимная функция.

```
[](int a, int b) -> int {
    return a * b;
}
```

Эта запись означает функцию*, которая получает `int`-параметры `a` и `b`, и возвращает их произведение. Аналогичную стандартную функцию можно записать так:

```
int f(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Конкретный тип этой функции не задан, поэтому для записи в переменную тип переменной объявлен как `auto`.

Лямбда-функция отличается от обыкновенной, например, тем, что она может ссылаться на локальные переменные окружающего метода, доступные в области видимости её объявления. Например:

```
int a = 5;

auto f2 = [&a](int b) -> int {
    return a * b;
}
```

Это производит функцию* с *одним* аргументом `b`.

---

Пример случая, где лямбда упрощает код. Допустим, вы хотите отсортировать массив чисел типа `double` по расстоянию до конкретного числа. Вы пишете просто вот так:

```
double pivot = 123.45;
std::sort(x, x + n, [=](double a, double b) { return abs(a - pivot) < abs(b - pivot); });
```

Без лямбд сделать такое было бы сложнее.

---

Вот более подробное описание: [[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd293608.aspx), [[2]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

---

*На самом деле это не совсем функция, а объект, который *ведёт себя* как функция. Отличие с точки зрения пользователя состоит, например, в том, что если что-то ожидает функцию как параметр, в него не получится так просто передать лямбду.

Comment: ну вообще говоря: **любая** функция _может ссылаться на переменные в области видимости её объявления_

Comment: все понял спасибо @VladD очень интересная вещь. но усложняющая код

Comment: @perfect, в некоторых случаях - упрощающая

Comment: @Grundy: Вы правы, уточнил.

Comment: @perfect: Обновил ответ, привёл пример, при котором лямбды упрощают жизнь.

Comment: Плюсанул бы за интересный исчерпывающий ответ, но дневные плюсы закончились:)

Comment: А  что есть "исчерпывающий ответ" это как-то отличается от обычных "стрелок" вверх\низ ?

Comment: @VladD я бы под алгоритм сорт лучше бы функтор или предикат написал. хотя и с лямбда функцией короче получилось.

Comment: «Это производит функцию с одним аргументом b» — если заниматься буквоедством, то это не так. Эта строчка производит callable object(closure), у которого есть состояние, который не является функцией. Те, что не имеют состояния, те — да, могут вырождаться в функции, но, всё равно, функциями, сами по себе, не являются.

Comment: @perfect: По сути лямбда и есть такой себе функтор. Но конкретно функтор во многих случаях выходит длиннее.

Comment: @perfect, это всё временно, пока Вы не оценили всех преимуществ лямбд. Потом, когда оцените, весь Ваш код будет в них

Comment: @ixSci: Согласен. Уточнил ответ.

Comment: @VladD, ещё одно интересное отличие, для пользователя, состоит в том, что от типа лямбды можно наследоваться. Вот [интересная](https://ngathanasiou.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/lambda-hackery-overloading-sfinae-and-copyrights/) статья в тему. Не думаю, что это нужно выносить в ответ, это для Вас, если не видели такого трюка ранее.

Comment: @ixSci: Класс, не знал, спасибо! Это означает, что можно создать «вручную» объект соответствующего типа? (Для ответа была бы, да, слишком специальная деталь.)

Comment: @VladD, да получается, что можно. Я ещё не исследовал всю глубину этой фичи(только недавно прочитал эту статью), но выглядит многообещающе. Как всегда, все применения новых фич языка находятся много позже их публикации