# Непонятная конструкция

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь разобрать чужой код, не понимаю что это за выражение :

```
precedence([value] {
        if (value == '*') {
            return 2;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }()
```

ясно как оно работает, но что за система? Лямбда выражение? Какой стандарт?

Comment: лямбда, да. Анонимная функция, начиная с с++11. Работает так, если value равно *, то вернет 2, иначе - 1. синтаксис лямбд лучше читать в интернете

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разьясните что это за странная конструкция и что она делает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485933/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8c%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82) (Не спрашивайте, как я это откопал, я сам не знаю)

Comment: Лямбда функция.

Answer (score 3):

Тут немножко не хватает - как минимум закрывающей скобки.

Часть (я переписал, чтоб не тягать многострочность)

```
[value] { return (value == '*') ? 2 : 1; }
```

представляет собой определение лямбда-выражения без передаваемых параметров, но захватывающего значение переменной `value`. Пара скобок `()` после него - вызов этого лямбда-выражения. Так что если добавить забытую закрывающую скобку, то получим

```
precedence( /* вызов лямбда-выражения */ );
```

Что это - вызов функции или часть объявления переменной - без контекста неясно. Кроме того, чтоб это работало - должна быть переменная `value`. Например, компилирующийся и работающий код мог бы иметь вид

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char value = '*';
    int precedence([value] { return (value == '*') ? 2 : 1; }());
    cout << precedence << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создадим альтернативный вариант

```
class Alternate {
    const char val;
 public:
    Alternate(const char& n) : val(n){}
    int operator ()() const {  return (val == '*') ? 2 : 1; }
} ;
```

ну и в программе

```
int main()
{             
   char value = '*';
   Alternate function_2(value);
   // альтернативный вариант будет выглядеть так:
   int precedence_2(function_2());

   // чтобы не определить функтор, просто использовано лямбда выражение
   // Лямбда выражение это анонимная функция. Приведенный вами пример
   // можно  написать  в  более читабельном виде
   auto function = [value] { return (value == '*') ? 2 : 1; };
   // function можно вызвать также как и другие функции(со скобками) 
   int precedence(function());
   // у вас написано то же самое.   
   cout << precedence << endl << precedence_2;    
   return 0;
}
```